# Can we connect to a database or service in a dmn?

Tags: drools, jbpm, dmn

We have two approach in our team about DMN diagrams. Which one is correct?

1. We can connect to database and services inside a DMN, Because:

   - we can't forecast what parameters are mandatory, so we call them by services on demand (or use lazy loading form a DB)
   - DMN Diagram has got a service element and be able to connect to another element so why don't we connect to a database or service too?
2. We have to provide all of the input in a DMN context before execution